# Не возможно сделать push запрос средствами GitLens из Visual Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Довольно-таки странная ситуация.
Есть два удаленных репозитария в одном аккаунте на Github. Когда делаю push запрос для одного из них, средствами GitLens или через терминал, все работает как должно. Когда я открываю второй проект, то push запрос работает только из терминала, а если отправлять его средствами GitLens выходит ошибка :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Повторюсь, при выполнении push из терминала, после ввода пароля в файлам ключей, запрос выполняется без проблем. Журнал Git:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходные данные Git:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что выводит если нажать "Показать выходные данные команды"?

Comment: Обновил в вопросе